# Yii multiple update of child records based on current parent record

Tags: yii

I am trying to come up with a way of updating multiple records of a model and as I am using YiiBooster I have seen that you can do bulk actions using the Extended Grid.

Most of the examples that I have found on the web are showing how to delete multiple records using Ajax but my requirements are slightly different. As a newbie to Yii I am struggling to work out a suitable solution to this.

Basically I have 2 models, a parent and a child with a one-to-many relation. In the child model I have a field which references which parent it belongs to using the parent ID.

In the front end of the application the user is supposed to navigate to the parent update view and then see a list of all children assigned to that parent. I have created a modal window that shows a grid list of all children with the ability to perform a bulk update action. This will then assign the parent ID to all of the children that were selected.

Can anyone help me out with this as I am unsure what I need to edit in the extended grid view and controller that will be used to update the records?

In my parent update view I pull in the index view of the children using renderPartial, as follows:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('application.modules.children.views.childviews.addChild', array('dataProvider' => new CActiveDataProvider('Children'))); ?>
```

I then have an Extended grid in my child index view:

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'type' => 'striped bordered',
    'id' => 'children-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'bulkActions' => array(
        'actionButtons' => array(
            array(
                'buttonType' => 'link',
                'type' => 'primary',
                'size' => 'small',
                'label' => 'Bulk Action',
                'url' => array('batchUpdate'),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'bulk-action'
                ),
                'id' => 'child_id',
                'click' => ''
            )
        ),
        'checkBoxColumnConfig' => array(
            'name' => 'child_id'
        ),
    ),
    'columns' => array(
        'child_id',
        'child_status',
        'parent_id',
        array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'buttons' => array(
                'update' => array(
                    'label' => '<i class="icon-user"></i> <span>View Child</span>',
                    'options' => array('class' => 'btn btn-small'),
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("children/update", array("id"=>$data->child_id))',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

I am guessing that I need some kind of onclick event that calls an update action in the controller and this action updates the parent_id column of all selected records to the parent id of the current parent update page?

I hope someone can help and many thanks in advance.

Comment: My question is, if you don't already have the parent_id in the child records, how are you going to display them with the parent?

Comment: At the moment the parent id is hardcoded into the child table. This is while I try and get the functionality working.

Ideally if there is no child records in a parent the page will tell the user that there are no records.

Many thanks

Comment: I guess my point is that there is no need for bulk assignment of the parent key. it should be assigned when you initially create the child.

Comment: This functionality is required by the client unfortunately. The parent is actually an auction and the children are properties so this means that the client will need to be able to assign properties to auctions and this would be very slow if it was done per property. The idea is that the client will go on auction id 1 and then assign multiple properties to that auction. PS. I like your blog, very informative!

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are doing now.  This isn't a one to many parent child relationship, it is a many to many parent child relationship where a given auction needs to be assigned properties from a list of pre-defined properties.  I will answer this evening after work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a one to many relationship as you stated in your question, it seams that you really want a many to many relationship. The reason I say that is you seem to want to select from a set of pre-defined properties for your auction.  In that case you would display the parent (auction), and the list of perspective children (properties), and using a checkbox or something like that to indicate the selection of the perspective children.  You will have to use a separate data model to record the selections.  I don't have an example right now, but I will need to do something like this in my current Yii project, and I will blog about it when I get there.

Comment: It has been a while, but here is my blog post on this topic http://jmmurphy.blogspot.com/2013/10/many-to-many-relationships-in-yii.html. I am using a CheckBoxList() to select the child records.